# Does jQuery .on() support for "load" or "ready" events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For attaching click event handler to dynamically loaded html, I could use:

```
$(document).on("click", "Parent_SELECTOR_Available_In_Initial", function(e){
  /// Do some stuff ...
});
```

I dynamically load some html mark up and JavaScript which contain methods need to be run on ready or load event, but this does  not work:

```
$(document).on("ready", "Parent_SELECTOR_Available_In_Initial", function(e){
  /// Do some stuff ...
});
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: any specific reason why `$(document).ready()` is out of the question?

Comment: @TimothyGroote: I think the idea is that code already on the page needs to run in response to new markup loading into `Parent_SELECTOR_Available_In_Initial` -- is that right, Mostafa?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Exactly .

Comment: Why don't you just put the on click event handler inside document ready?

Comment: @TimothyGroote you can also use `$().ready()` since `$()` is an alias of `$(document)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to do that ?

There are two:

1. [Trigger a custom event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) when you load the data into `Parent_SELECTOR_Available_In_Initial`, or
2. Use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on `Parent_SELECTOR_Available_In_Initial` and watch either or both the `subtree` and/or `childList`.

Mutation observers are [supported by most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) with the notable exception of IE9 and IE10. But IE9 and IE10 support (most of) the old [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), and the nice folks at Polymer have done [a polyfill](https://github.com/polymer/MutationObservers) that implements (most of) mutation observers using mutation events.

For really old browsers like IE8, you'll have to poll with `setInterval`.